# Two level menu android using AppCompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have this menu on my android app

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.app.MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="root"
    app:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:title="item 1"
            app:showAsAction="always" />
        <item
            android:title="item 2"
            app:showAsAction="always" />
        <item
            android:title="item 3"
            app:showAsAction="always" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

On API 14+ it works as expected: click on button gives me dropdown menu.

But on API 8 it works strange
[image: API 8]

Where is my problem? What should I do?

Comment: what is strange about it?

Comment: I expect dropdown on API 8 as if I use Sherlock

Comment: API 8 does not have this ability, the thing you speak of is a PopupMenu which was added in API 11. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html